# Using transform() in the QGIS function editor?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to transform coordinates of a feature for part of a script to populate a calculated attribute field.

This works in the expression box:

```
x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'))
```

This is how I tried to implement that in the function editor:

```
def gridLocation(value1, feature, parent):

    place = feature.geometry()
    tr = QgsCoordinateTransform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')
    place.transform(tr)

    x_val = place.asPoint().x()
    # ...
```

but `x_val` is still returning the original x value.

What's the proper way to use transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things you could change:

- Add `usesgeometry=True` as another parameter to your function.
- You can remove `value1` as you're not really using this.
- In your `tr = QgsCoordinateTransform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')` line, replace `EPSG:4326` with `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)` and repeat with `EPSG:3857`.

---

The following works for me:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesgeometry=True)
def gridLocation(feature, parent):
    place = feature.geometry()
    tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326),QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857))
    place.transform(tr)
    x_val = place.asPoint().x()

    #Add return statement to return values to the attribute table
    return x_val
```

Comment: Thanks! It appears it was a simple as replacing the CRS ID strings with their their respective QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem() id.


Also, I didn't return x_val because my script continued to do thing with the x and y values and returned something else.

Comment: @grahamalama - Most welcome! You're correct about the replacement, although I did also have to use `usesgeometry=True` otherwise I receive an error about transforming 'NoneTypes'.